# Premature end of file, direct upload youtube

Tags: php, zend-framework, file-upload, youtube, youtube-api

I am trying to upload a video to youtube, using the direct upload method as explained [here, at documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_php).

I have included my developer key correctly, and am getting the session token too without any problem. The problem appears when it directs me to the upload page with the token. Instead of uploading and returning with the video id, it shows me a single line,

> Premature end of file.

I am new to zend as well as using youtube api's for the first time, I managed to work out authentication and few errors, that were shown but I have no idea, why or where is this problem.

Here is my php file,

```
<?php

session_start();

require_once 'Zend/Loader.php'; // the Zend dir must be in your include_path
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_YouTube');
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_AuthSub');
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Uri_Http');


function getAuthSubRequestUrl()
{
    $next = 'http://localhost/trial/trial.php';
    $scope = 'http://gdata.youtube.com';
    $secure = false;
    $session = true;
    return Zend_Gdata_AuthSub::getAuthSubTokenUri($next, $scope, $secure, $session);
}

//generate link if no session or token has been requested
if (!isset($_SESSION['sessionToken']) && !isset($_GET['token'])){

  echo '<a href="' . getAuthSubRequestUrl() . '">Login to YouTube API!</a>';

  //if token has been requested but not saved to a session then save the new token to a session 
} else if (!isset($_SESSION['sessionToken']) && isset($_GET['token'])) {

  $_SESSION['sessionToken'] = Zend_Gdata_AuthSub::getAuthSubSessionToken($_GET['token']);

}


if(isset($_SESSION['sessionToken'])) {

    $clientLibraryPath = '/library';
    $oldPath = set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . $clientLibraryPath);

    $sessionToken = $_SESSION['sessionToken'];
    $developerKey = 'my-key-here';   //I have inserted the key correctly.

    $httpClient = new Zend_Gdata_HttpClient();
    $httpClient->setAuthSubToken($sessionToken);

    $yt = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube($httpClient, '23', '234', $developerKey);

    $myVideoEntry = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube_VideoEntry();

    $file= '../path_to_file/filename.mp4';
    $file = realpath($file);  

   $filesource = $yt->newMediaFileSource($file); 

   // create a new Zend_Gdata_App_MediaFileSource object
   $filesource = $yt->newMediaFileSource('file.mov');
   $filesource->setContentType('video/quicktime');
   // set slug header
   $filesource->setSlug('file.mov');
   $myVideoEntry->setVideoTitle('My Test Movie'); 
   $myVideoEntry->setVideoDescription('My Test Movie'); 

   $myVideoEntry->setVideoCategory('Entertainment');  
   $myVideoEntry->SetVideoTags('testme');  
   $myVideoEntry->setVideoDeveloperTags(array('tester', 'test'));  

   $uploadUrl = 'http://uploads.gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default/uploads';  


try {  
        $newEntry = $yt->insertEntry($myVideoEntry, $uploadUrl, 'Zend_Gdata_YouTube_VideoEntry'); 

    } catch (Zend_Gdata_App_HttpException $httpException) {   

       echo $httpException->getRawResponseBody();

    } catch (Zend_Gdata_App_Exception $e) {

       echo $e->getMessage();

    }
}
?>
```

Thanks. Please ask for further explanations or information regarding the problem or code if required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use the Data API instead and utilize the resumable upload. [Here's a PHP upload example](https://github.com/youtube/yt-samples-php/blob/master/resumable_upload.php).